# Getting the EFS Private Key out of system image

Tags: windows-7, encryption

I had to recently re-install Windows 7 and I lost my exported private key for EFS. I however have the entirety of my user directory and my figuring that the key must be in there SOMEWHERE. The only question is how to get it out.

I did find the PUBLIC keys in AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\My\Certificates
If I import them using certmg.msc it says I do have the private key in the information, but if I try export them it says I do not have the private key. Also, decryption of files doesn't work.

There is also a "keys" folder at AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\My\Keys. After importing the certificates I copy those over into my new installation but it has no effect.

I am starting to believe they are either in AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Protect\S-1-5-21-...\ or AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\S-1-5-21-...\ but I am unsure how to use the files in those folders. Also, since my SID has changed, will I be able to use them? The other parts of the account have remained the same (name and password). I also have complete access to the user registry hive and most of the old system files (including the old system registry hives).

I do keep seeing references to "Key Recovery Agent" but have not found anything about using, just that it can be used.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found out that your user password, user+machine SID, and a salt are used to encrypt the Master Password (stored in AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Protect) which is in turn used to encrypt all private keys with another salt (in AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA). There are some guides out there on the basic format of the files in these folders and how they are encrypted. However there are missing pieces so a complete solution will take tinkering.

A free solution is to create a machine with the same machine SID (need to use XP and the program newsid - newsid does not work on Vista and later) and then a user with the same SID, copy the files over (the entirety of the Crypto, Protect, and System Certificates folder), and export from there. I did this with a virtual machine.

These assume you have access to all the original files. The Elcomsoft Advanced EFS Data Recovery program mentioned by Brian can also search sector-by-sector for the proper information. It also does not require creating a new installation or re-making the SID. So for most cases that one will be MUCH easier, however for people who want to do it free, see above.

Comment: Would it be possible to include a bit more instructions, e.g. how do you read SID (user and machine) from the system image / mounted disk?

Comment: Also: you can use NewSid to change machine SID, but how do you change user SID? Registry?

Answer (score 2):

The certificates/keys etc stored in the old profile are protected/encrypted by the user password hashed with the some other information. So you need to both find them and figure a way to decrypt them.

Elcomsoft offers a program to do the searching and decrypting. 
Elcomsoft - [Advanced EFS Data Recovery](http://elcomsoft.com/products.html) (near bottom of page) but with work you can accomplish the same yourself using online guides it's just a lot more work.

Answer (score 1):

I successfully recovered a PFX file (including the private key) in my Windows 10 1903 following this wiki from the `mimikatz` repository on GitHub: [Decrypt EFS files](https://github.com/gentilkiwi/mimikatz/wiki/howto-~-decrypt-EFS-files).

You just need to [download the `mimikatz` program here](https://github.com/gentilkiwi/mimikatz/releases) and [openssl for Windows](https://sourceforge.net/projects/openssl/) from here.

The steps are actually very simple. Pay attention for the master keys guid and other important ID's that the guide shows you. Files in `C:\Users\[YOUR USER]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Protect\[YOUR USER ID]` have system flags on them. To see them, just open `cmd.exe` in the folder and use the command `dir /A`.

One note is that **you need the account password for that**. In my case, I knew my account password so decrypting the masterkey wasn't a problem.

Comment: "The site ahead contains harmful programs", warns Chrome about the mimikatz download page